# For a possibly negative random variable, what does $0$ expectation and an expression for the random variable that is true $\mathbb{P}$ a.s. imply?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

The basic set up is that for some probability space ($\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}$), we have some random variable $X$, such that $\mathbb{E}X = 0$ and that $X = Y - Z, \quad \mathbb{P}  -a.s$, for some other random variables $Y$ and $Z$.

So from this I wrote: $\mathbb{P}(X = Y - Z) = \mathbb{P}\{\omega  \ | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\} = 1$, and for example in the discrete case:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}X & =  \sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega) * \mathbb{P}(\omega) \\ &= X(\{\omega | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\})  \; * \mathbb{P}\{\omega  \ | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\} \\
&= X(\{\omega | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\}) \\
&= Y(\omega) - Z(\omega) = 0
\end{align}

Does this mean that $Y = Z \quad \mathbb{P}  -a.s$, or am I making some error in logic here? I was also wondering how to show this in the continuous case, or if it's as simple as replacing the summation with $\mathbb{E}X = \int X(\omega)d \mathbb{P}(\omega)$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sadly, your conclusion is wrong! If $\mathbf E X =0$, and $X=Y-Z$ a.s., the only thing you know is that $\mathbf E Y = \mathbf E Z$.

Comment: Ah, I think my error is in writing $X(\{\omega | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\}) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)$, for all $\omega \in \Omega$

Comment: What is $X(\{\omega | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\})$ ? $X(\cdot)$ is a random variable so it cannot take a set as an argument; or do you use a different definition?

Comment: Sorry, but your working out of $\mathbb EX$ makes no sense.

Comment: It looks like I confused a measure vs. a measurable mapping, and was using the wrong definitions. I need to brush up on my basics. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega_1 = \{ \omega | X(\omega) = Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)\}$ and $\Omega_2$ be the complement of $\Omega_1$ in $\Omega$. Then $\mathbf P(\Omega_1) = 1$ and $\mathbf P(\Omega_2) = 0$.

Then we have
$$\begin{align} \mathbf E X &= \sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega) \mathbf P(\omega) \\
& = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega_1} X(\omega) \mathbf P(\omega) + \sum_{\omega \in \Omega_2} X(\omega) \mathbf P(\omega) \\ 
& = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega_1} [Y(\omega) - Z(\omega)] \mathbf P(\omega) \\ 
& = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega_1} Y(\omega) \mathbf P(\omega)  - \sum_{\omega \in \Omega_1} Z(\omega) \mathbf P(\omega) \\ 
&= \mathbf E Y - \mathbf E Z = 0,
\end{align}$$
as long as $\mathbf EY$ and $\mathbf E Z$ are defined (thanks drhab).

The same exact formulas hold in the continuous case (using integrals).

Answer (score 1):

From $X=U$ a.s. it can concluded that: $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EU$$

Applying this for $U=Y-Z$ we find: $$0=\mathbb EX=\mathbb E(Y-Z)$$

Under the extra condition that (at least one of) the expectations $\mathbb EY$ and $\mathbb EZ$ exists - this leads to:  $$\mathbb EY=\mathbb EZ$$